# understanding the variable creation

Tags: javascript

```
var counter = {
   count: 0,
   inc: function(){
       this.count++;
   }
}
counter.inc();
count;
//reference error: count is not defined
```

But when I use variable and call the function:

```
var counter = {
   count: 0,
   inc: function(){
       this.count++;
   }
}
var func = counter.inc;
func();
count;
// returns NaN Because func() runs window.count++
```

My question is that without using variable and call the function, why isn't it creating count variable?

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  counter.inc()   not equal to window.count++                   |
|  but func() equal to window.count++                            |
|                                                                |
+-------Why?-----------------------------------------------------+
```

---

My Key Question is:

> Why it's different counter.inc() and var func = counter.inc;func() ?

Comment: Because *count* is created as a property of the Object assigned to *counter*, it isn't a global variable. When you call *func*, you are calling the *inc* function without setting *this*, so it defaults to the global (window in a browser) object, and `this.count++` resolves to `window.count++`, and since there is no *window.count* property, accessing it returns *undefined* which the `++` operator can't increment .

Comment: Can you please verify it in your answer what exactly you want to say?

Comment: but why it's different counter.inc() and var func = counter.inc;func() ???

Comment: because you stored the function reference in the `func` var. it's `this` is now window instead of `counter`

Comment: I don't see how you aren't getting this given either of the two answers and the comments. What are you not understanding?

Comment: I'm just confusing in variable creates this but not in direct calling

Comment: Oh! another thing I came to know that if I use `return` then it's not having the problem, as what I expect is working...

Comment: how are you using return?

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference in your original code, are you sure you didn't change something else too?

Comment: yes, you may try it...

Answer (score 1):

Preliminary:

When the expression:

```
this.count++;
```

is evaluated, *this* references the global (window in a browser) object, so it is effectively:

```
window.count++;
```

The reason *this* references the global object is explained in answers to other questions.

> My question is that without using variable and call the function, why isn't it creating count variable?

It is creating *count* as a property of the global object, which is very similar to using a variable statement (i.e. `var count`) but has subtle differences explained elsewhere.

When evaluating the expression:

```
window.count++
```

Firstly *window.count* is resolved. Since *window* doesn't have a *count* property, it returns *undefined*. The [`++`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.4) operator then causes evaluation of *[ToNumber](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)(undefined)*, which returns *NaN*. It then attempts to add 1 to *NaN*, per the rules for the [*+*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.3) operator, which will return *NaN*.

It will then call *[PutValue(window.count, NaN)](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.2)* and since *window.count* doesn't exist, it will create it and assign the value *NaN*.

#### Edit

When you call the function as:

```
counter.inc();
```

then *this* within the function is the *counter* object, so:

```
this.count++;
```

increments the value of its *count* property.

When you do:

```
var func = counter.inc;
func();
```

then *this* within the function isn't set by the call, so it defaults to the global object. The above tells you why that results in *window.count* being set to *NaN*, which would occur for any property or variable whose value resolves to *NaN* when *ToNumber* is applied to it.

If you were to create a global *count* variable and initialise it to a number value (say `0`) before calling *func*:

```
var count = 0;
func();
```

then calling *func* would result in its value being incremented.

Comment: I'm not asking for returning value of NaN but the difference between using storing variable and calling function and direct calling the function without storing it in variable.

Comment: No, if I do counter.inc() then it shows an error count is not defined. But you are saying it's incrementing, try it once without using return. That's part I'm not understanding.

Comment: There is no need for a return statement since the return value is irrelevant. All that is of interest is what value is assigned to *this* within the function **when it's called** since that is the object on which the *count* property will be resolved and which an attempt will be made to increment using the `++` operator. If *this* is set to *counter* using `counter.inc()` then *counter.count* is incremented. If *this* isn't set, as in `func()`, its *this* isn't set so it defaults to the global object and so the `++` operator increments `window.count`.

Answer (score 1):

When you stored the anonymous function that is stored in `counter.inc` in `func`, it's default context became `window`. Then, when you called `func`, since you didn't pass in a context, it's context defaulted to `window` which doesn't have a count property. `window.count++` results in `window.count` being set to `NaN` since `window.count` is undefined.

```
window.prop = 2;
var A = {
    prop: 1,
    go: function () {
        console.log(this.prop);
    }
}
A.go(); // 1
var B = {
    prop: 3,
    go: A.go
}
B.go(); // 3
window.go = A.go;
window.go(); // 2
```

Comment: The value of *this* is set **by the call**, it is never set by where or how a function is defined. The reason calling the function sets *this* to *window* is because it's called without setting the base reference (and has nothing to do with (execution) context).

Comment: hmm... that confuses even me.

Comment: See [*MDN: this*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: What part of it? [this?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method) it seems to mimic the point i'm trying to make. It doens't matter where the function is defined or how it is defined, what does matter is where the function is stored when it is executed. Is it executed as a member of window? a member of A? of B?

Comment: are we just having a difference in terminology?

Comment: No problem with terminology. The statement "When you stored the … function … its this context became window" should have been something like "When you called the function without setting its *this*, it defaulted to the global object". Maybe that's what you meant, but it's not how what you wrote comes across.

Comment: I see what you mean. Just because the function is *stored* in A doesn't mean it's context will be A. It just happens to be A in that case because we didn't set the context to something else. The same goes for window when we store it in window.func